# How to print a word with specific character in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, compare

Sample Input: Stack Overflow is Awesome

Character to Search: e

Output: Ov**e**rflow Aw**e**some

I wrote a code to split a string by space and store as words but i don't know how to check and print the result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char str1[100];
char newString[10][10]; 
int i,j,ctr;
   printf("\n\n Split string by space into words :\n");
   printf("---------------------------------------\n");    

printf(" Input  a string : ");
fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);    

j=0; ctr=0;
for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
{
    // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
    if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
    {
        newString[ctr][j]='\0';
        ctr++;  //for next word
        j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
    }
    else
    {
        newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
        j++;
    }
}
printf("\n Strings or words after split by space are :\n");
for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
    printf(" %s\n",newString[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strchr()` to easily check a string for a specific chararacter

```
for (i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
    if (strchr(newString[i], 'e') != NULL) {
        printf(" %s\n", newString[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines at end to your code to print the filtered strings/words by character `e`

```
printf("\n Strings or words Containing character 'e' :\n");
for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
   if(strchr(newString[i], 'e') != NULL) 
      printf(" %s\n",newString[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are parsing str1 in order to find the beginning and the end of each word, why not using the for loop to detect if the current word contain the letter that you search ?

There are many little "error" too : do not use "strlen" in the for loop, it will be call each time ! Instead, detect '\0' !
Your result array newString is unsafe ! It should be [50][100] because you can input a string of one word with 100 char ( so [1][100] ) or 50 letter and 50 blank (so [50][2] ). So the result array must be [50][100] in order to take any possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split the string using the `strtok` and using the `strchr` to check if the substring contains the letter *e*. In this way you can loop a single time over the original string and perform both the splitting and the checking.
Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="Stack Overflow is Awesome";
    char* pch;
    char* pch2;
    //split string by spaces
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        //check if the substring contains the letter 'e'
        pch2 = strchr(pch,'e');
        if (pch2 != NULL) {
            printf ("%s\n",pch);
        }
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```